# Generate encrypted password for WSSE authentification

Tags: php, symfony, encryption, fosuserbundle, ws-security

I have a backboneJS application that communicate with a Restfull API write with Symfony2. 
To authenticate the user, an HTTP header (WSSE) is sent to all queries.

The header looks like this:

```
X-WSSE:UsernameToken Username="foo@goo.com", PasswordDigest="clrGx4hSEyC3zdndd04/51yuee7Q=", Nonce="VURQQWQ0RTBMSGo4enBCN05GSjNuTGhsSjF3PQ==", Created="2014-05-09T15:11:06+02:00"
```

For generate the passwordDigest, I need to have the user password encrypted. For testing, I have put this password encrypted directly in my frontEnd.

So, for create a générique method and not sent the password encrypted on the network, I need to generate the same password encrypted in my front End.

The User try to connect:

- User write is email
- Application try to get the salt for this email
- User write is password
- Application created the same encrypted password that this base

Anyone know how to encrypt the password on the client side (in javascript), with the password (enter by the user) and the salt?

Thank's !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various libraries available for encryption on the client side. [Forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) is a library which implements a few message digest functions in JS, including SHA-1 which is what you seem to be using currently.

Comment: The password is crypted with FOSUserBundle sha512.
In my security.yml, I have this: FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: Forge doesn't support SHA-512, probably for performance reasons. I would suggest switching to SHA-256. You can simply replace `sha512` with `sha256` in your config. The Symfony core encoder uses the PHP [`hash_algos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) function to check for algorithms supported on your system.

Comment: Finaly, I've used https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ including sha512 Algorithme ! Thank's ;)